# running emulator on eclipse not working

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

Im new to eclipse. I was following a tutorial on youtube, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-C-QPGR2pM, which creates a flash light app on eclipse. When I was trying to run it was not working. When selecting run as : android application a pop up screen appeared.

No compatible targets were found. Do you wish to add a new virtual android device?

I do not know what to do at this point.

The tutorial does not have this problem.

Comment: Did you install the android virtual machine?

Comment: Check out http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html and http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html.

Answer (score 2):

For running an Emulator instance, you will have to create a virtual android device. For this you will need the AVD - In Eclipse click "Window -> Android SDK and AVD manager"
Click create new AVD and this screen will pop up. Create the virtual device and your ready to go.

[image: Create new AVD]

Comment: Thank you. I did what you said but all i got was a screen that said android. It did not become a phone. It became a big black screen and in the middle android as if it was loading.

Comment: Also after closing the screen another box opened up and I started the emulator again. As it was opening I got this message."### WARNING: SD Card files must be at least 9MB, ignoring '/Users/roybenmoshe/Documents/Flashlight/Flashlight_Prefix.pch'
2011-10-12 06:38:36.363 emulator-arm[1899:80b] Warning once: This application, or a library it uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz."

Comment: Set the SD cards size to over 9 mb in the edit emulator window. When the black screen with the Android logo turns up after running the emulator, you will have to wait! its initializing the device, and the first time that can take some time. Just wait and it will show up. Best regards Jonas